# How to serialize params in AngularJS $resource to a rails 3.2 compatible params

Tags: angularjs, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to get angular resource to serialize my object properly to a rails 3.2 controller action. The data format is JSON and the working and required input (on Rails side) should be:

```
"data"=>[{"id"=>29, "column"=>0, "position"=>0}], "id"=>"2", "page"=>{}
```

This works with our old code:

```
$.ajax
  type: "put"
  url: target
  dataType: "json"
  contentType: "application/json"
  data: JSON.stringify({data: widgets})
```

However if I try with angular resource I get something like below instead:

```
"data"=>"[{\"id\":28,\"column\":2,\"position\":0}]", "id"=>"2", "page"=>{"id"=>"2"}
```

I first created a factory:

```
app.factory "Page", ["$resource", ($resource) ->
  $resource "/admin/pages/:collectionRoute:id/:memberRoute",
  {
    id: "@id",
    memberRoute: "@memberRoute",
    collectionRoute: "@collectionRoute",
  },
  {
    update: {method: "PUT"}
    store_widgets: { method: "PUT", params: { data: "@data", memberRoute: 'store_widgets' }, isArray: true }
  }
]
```

... and called the `store_widgets` function with:

```
Page.store_widgets(id: $scope.page_id, data: JSON.stringify(widgets) )
```

I've tried a few alternatives to setting the data parameter but it doesn't seem to work.  It's either posted as `[Object object]` or as plain string.

Any suggestions on how I might get the request sent by $resource to be exactly like the one that is working using pure jQuery Ajax?

Answer (score 1):

Depending on whether you want `data` to be passed in request body or in query params:

In query params:

```
// 'store_widgets' action definition
store_widgets: {
  method: "PUT",
  params: {
    id: "@id",
    data: "@data",
    memberRoute: 'store_widgets'
  },
  isArray: true
}
```

Call:

```
function MyCtrl($scope, Page) {

  $scope.widget = [
    {"id":29, "column":0, "position":0}
  ];

  Page.store_widgets({id: 2, data: $scope.widget, page: {}});

}
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2OlybKTPVx61Pi3eGwzC).

---

In request body:

Call:

```
Page.store_widgets({id: 2, page: {}}, {data: $scope.widget});
```

---

Ass $resource docs say:

> The action methods on the class object or instance object can be invoked with the following parameters:
>
> 1. HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success], [error])
> 2. non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData, [success], [error])
> 3. non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters], [success], [error])

Comment: That's what I thought but there is no serialization taking place. Whatever I send as data: is just converted to a string. Probably with `toString()` and the output becomes `{"id"=>"2", "data"=>"[object Object]", "page"=>{}}`

Comment: If you take a look at the console (while running my plunker) you'll see that data is properly serialized. Maybe you could setup your own plunker, reproducing the issue. Otherwise it would be hard to debug this.

Comment: You are right, sorry about that. Should have done that right away. Be back in a sec

Comment: Ok I found the problem. for some reason `param: { data: "@data" }` seems to convert my object to a string. if I remove that it's serialized fine any ideas on that?

Answer (score 1):

The only way was I able to solve serializing my parameters so I could see the data in a PHP POST channel was to use JQuery.param().

I had to set the header in my $resource:

```
headers : {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
```

My call to $resource methods.
This is quick and dirty so please forgive.

```
vm.save = function(item) { 
  var data = $.param({username:item.username, email:item.email});
  userFactory.save(data);
}
```

I had to pull the data out of `item` since $resouce attached methods to `item`. If you use `$.param` on `item` it ended up firing all the DELETE, GET, QUERY, etc.. methods attached to the resource.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is solved in the 2.0 version of angular(

look here: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3740